# Underlines of TextFormFields in form not uniform no matter what I do. How to keep a uniform thickness for all underlines of TextFormFields?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm brand new to flutter and building a form in Flutter containing multiple `TextFormField`s, and a radio button. But, something weird is happening where the textformfields above the radio buttons are not uniform and keep changing randomly based on other changes I make. In my [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL8by.png), you can see the first 3 text fields are uniform, but the one after the radio button is lighter. This is the closest I've come to achieving uniform text field underlines. I've tried adding and removing a lot of things such as padding, sized boxes, containers, etc, and they affect the underlines in different ways.

For instance, changing the mainAxisAlignment under `Form->Column->Padding` to 'start' instead of `spaceEvenly` causes the 1st 3 underlines to have thickness in increasing order and the last text box is fine [Check screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mocmi.png). How can I make it so that all the underlines of the `TextFormFields` are equally thick and uniform irrespective of any other changes I make? Is there any better way of doing radio buttons than what I have done? Is there a better element in flutter than radio buttons for what I have done? I would also love it if I could make the radio buttons horizontal instead of vertical. The underlines are working fine and not fading in chrome, but they are in android emulator (Pixel 5 API30). I want this to work regardless of platform.

**`main.dart`:**

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:hospital_finance_app/pages/OPD.dart';
    import 'package:hospital_finance_app/pages/login_page.dart';
    import 'package:hospital_finance_app/utils/routes.dart';
    import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(const hospApp());
    }
    
    class hospApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const hospApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Login Demo',
          home: OPD(),
        );
      }
    }
```

**`OPD.dart:`**

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    import 'package:hospital_finance_app/utils/routes.dart';
    
    enum paymentMethod { Cash, Other }
    
    class OPD extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<OPD> createState() => _OPDState();
    }
    
    class _OPDState extends State<OPD> {
      paymentMethod? _method = paymentMethod.Cash;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Material(
              child: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.black),
                body: Form(
                  child:Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                          TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Name",
                            hintText: "Name",
                          ),
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Mobile number", 
                            labelText: "Mobile Number"),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
                          
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Amount",
                            hintText: "Amount"),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
                          
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text("Mode of Payment", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black54, fontFamily: "OpenSans", fontWeight: FontWeight.w400 ), textAlign: TextAlign.left),alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,),
                        Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                          title: const Text('Cash'),
                          leading: Radio<paymentMethod>(
                            value: paymentMethod.Cash,
                            groupValue: _method,
                            onChanged: (paymentMethod? value) {
                              setState(() {
                                _method = value;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          title: const Text('Other'),
                          leading: Radio<paymentMethod>(
                            value: paymentMethod.Other,
                            groupValue: _method,
                            onChanged: (paymentMethod? value) {
                              setState(() {
                                _method = value;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                         
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Comments/Notes",hintText: "Comments/Notes"),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed:(){ Navigator.pushNamed(context, MyRoutes.opdRoute); },
                              child: Text("Submit"),
                              style: TextButton.styleFrom(minimumSize: Size(100,30)),)
                    ]
                ),
                  )
                      ),
              ));
      }
    }
```

Screen shot of my application on android emulator with mainAxisAlignment spaceEvenly

[image: Screen shot of my application on android emulator with mainAxisAlignment spaceEvenly.]

Screen shot of my application on android emulator with mainAxisAlignment  start.

[image: Screen shot of my application on android emulator with mainAxisAlignment start.]

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is not clear enough. The TL;DR is that the underlines of my TextFormFields are volatile and not uniform. This is probably because of some structural error where I'm using the wrong widgets or in the wrong order. Please tell me a way wherein I can fix the thickness of the underlines make them uniform now and in the future when I make other changes like adding more text fields, padding, containers, images, etc. The screenshots give 2 examples of how the underlines are changing in response to something seemingly not connected.

Comment: for better understanding please try this in Physical device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a bug from the android emulator. try running your app on a real device.

Comment: I'd suspected that this might be a bug but since making a form is such a common use case, I assumed that there would be a lot of stackoverflow questions about this if it was a bug. Anyway, I'm charging up my old phone, I'll update in a few hours if this was indeed a bug or not.

Comment: It isn't bug, the shadow of each TextFormField overlap if placed one after another.

Comment: thanks, this was indeed a bug. The underlines work perfectly on my android device.

Answer (score 0):

When you use mainAxisAlignment as 'start', all the TextFormFields are placed one after another without any spacing between them, so the line thickness is increased (two lines overlap).
Instead, when you spaceEvenly, TextFormFields are separated and the line appears thin, the original thickness.

Comment: Give some bottom margin to your TextFormField, to make thickness appear uniform.

Comment: I wrapped the column containing the TextFormFields in a container and gave it bottom margin `margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4)` but it didn't solve the issue. Now the mobile number textbox (2nd from the top) is thick and the others are faint.

Comment: You have to wrap each TextFormField separately with Container and provide margin. Alternatively, just use SizedBox(height: 4) after each TextFormField.

Comment: I tried both your suggestions but both don't work. I can see the thickness of the lines changing as I adjust the margin, but the thickness is still not uniform, there is always some text field which is thicker than the others. Also, this is really tedious since I plan to add more widgets, I don't want to waste hours just adjusting margins. Is there any recommended way to do this or is flutter just shitty at building forms?